# << operator overloading and template specialization

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-specialization

As part of study purpose, I was just playing with template specialization together with operator overloading

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void operator<<(std::ostream& COUT,T val)
{
   std::operator<<(COUT,val); //works for basic data types
}

//specializing for const char*
template<>
void operator<<(std::ostream& COUT,const char* val)
{
    std::operator<<(COUT,val);
}
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"samplestring"; //getting error here
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting following error which I cannot figure out.

```
<source>:17:14: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'const char [13]')
   17 |     std::cout<<"samplestring";
      |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |          |     |
      |          |     const char [13]
      |          std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
```

what is the problem here

Thank you..!

Comment: Suggest making your functions do something other than just printing the value, so you can tell for certain whether or not your function was actually called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there is already `operator<<(std::ostream& COUT,const char* val)` defined by the standard library.

So now there are two symbols

```
std::operator<<(std::ostream& ostream,const char* val);
operator<<(std::ostream& COUT,const char* val); // YOURS
```

Because the symbols are different, there are no multiple-definition errors.

For a call `std::cout << "Hello"`, the compiler searches for all `operator<<` functions currently defined at the call site. That looks like it is just your function, but the compiler also looks into all namespaces in which the passed arguments are defined. In this case it is `std::` namespace and there the compiler finds the STL version. That is called argument dependent lookup(ADL).

Since both functions are templates and neither is more specialized than the other, the call is ambiguous.

Please do not use all capital letters as variable `COUT`, that is usually reserved for macros, with one-letter template parameters being exception `T`.

> //works for basic data types

That is also not true, `std::cout<<5;` will NOT call your definition with `T`. Because there exists [`std::ostream::operator<<(int v)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) method. Same lookup happens but since this method is not a template, it is a better candidate and thus chosen. Your template function is never called.

Comment: @jtr Also explained the basic data types calls.

Comment: Picking nits, but "the compiler looks into all namespaces in which the _arguments' types_ are defined". (Arguments are the expressions passed in to a function call. Parameters are the variables described within the function declarator, which get initialized by the arguments.)

Comment: @aschepler You are right, I guess that is why it is ADL, not PDL ;)

Comment: @Quimby , very well explained. Thank you. I got the point and wrapped my operators into a "sample" namespace and it worked.